# Merging data from python list into one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following files in AAMC_K.txt, AAU.txt, ACU.txt, ACY.txt in a folder called AMEX. I am trying to merge these text files into one dataframe. I have tried to do so with pd.merge() but I get an error that the merge function needs a right and left parameter and my data is in a python list. How can I merge the data in the data_list into one pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

textfile_names = os.listdir("AMEX")
textfile_names.sort()
data_list = []

for i in range(len(textfile_names)):
   data = pd.read_csv("AMEX/"+textfile_names[i], index_col=None, header=0)
   data_list.append(data)

frame = pd.merge(data_list, on='<DTYYYYMMDD>', how='outer')

"AE.txt"
<TICKER>,<PER>,<DTYYYYMMDD>,<TIME>,<OPEN>,<HIGH>,<LOW>,<CLOSE>,<VOL>,<OPENINT>
AE,D,19970102,000000,12.6250,12.6250,11.7500,11.7500,144,0
AE,D,19970103,000000,11.8750,12.1250,11.8750,12.1250,25,0

AAU.txt
<TICKER>,<PER>,<DTYYYYMMDD>,<TIME>,<OPEN>,<HIGH>,<LOW>,<CLOSE>,<VOL>,<OPENINT>
AAU,D,20020513,000000,0.4220,0.4220,0.4220,0.4220,0,0
AAU,D,20020514,000000,0.4177,0.4177,0.4177,0.4177,0,0

ACU.txt
<TICKER>,<PER>,<DTYYYYMMDD>,<TIME>,<OPEN>,<HIGH>,<LOW>,<CLOSE>,<VOL>,<OPENINT>
ACU,D,19970102,000000,5.2500,5.3750,5.1250,5.1250,52,0
ACU,D,19970103,000000,5.1250,5.2500,5.0625,5.2500,12,0

ACY.txt
<TICKER>,<PER>,<DTYYYYMMDD>,<TIME>,<OPEN>,<HIGH>,<LOW>,<CLOSE>,<VOL>,<OPENINT>
ACY,D,19980116,000000,9.7500,9.7500,8.8125,8.8125,289,0
ACY,D,19980120,000000,8.7500,8.7500,8.1250,8.1250,151,0
```

I want the output to be filtered with the DTYYYYMMDD and put into one dataframe frame.

```
OUTPUT
<TICKER>,<PER>,<DTYYYMMDD>,<TIME>,<OPEN>,<HIGH>,<LOW>,<CLOSE>,<VOL>,<OPENINT>,<TICKER>,<PER>,<DTYYYMMDD>,<TIME>,<OPEN>,<HIGH>,<LOW>,<CLOSE>,<VOL>,<OPENINT>
ACU,D,19970102,000000,5.2500,5.3750,5.1250,5.1250,52,0,AE,D,19970102,000000,12.6250,12.6250,11.7500,11.7500,144,0
ACU,D,19970103,000000,5.1250,5.2500,5.0625,5.2500,12,0,AE,D,19970103,000000,11.8750,12.1250,11.8750,12.1250,25,0
```

Comment: What you probably want is `pd.concat`

Comment: I want to merge the data in the data_list using the parameter how='outer' in the pd.merge(). After that I want to use the same function but with the parameter how='inner' and the parameter on='<DTYYYYMMDD>' so it gives me the intersection between all the columns

Comment: What output are you expecting? It might help to give the example dataframes instead of text files since importing the csv file doesn't seem to be part of the problem.

Comment: edited the question and wrote what the output I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

As @busybear says, `pd.concat` is the right tool for this job: `frame = pd.concat(data_list)`.

`merge` is for when you're joining two dataframes which usually have some of the same columns and some different ones. You choose a column (or index or multiple) which identifies which rows in the two dataframes correspond to each other, and `pandas` handles making a dataframe whose rows are combinations of the corresponding rows in the two original dataframes. This function only works on 2 dataframes at a time; you'd have to do a loop to merge more in (it's uncommon to need to merge many dataframes this way).

`concat` is for when you have multiple dataframes and want to just append all of their rows or columns into one large dataframe. (Let's assume you're concatenating rows, as you want here.) It doesn't use an identifier to determine which rows correspond. All it does is create a new dataframe which has each row from each of the `concat`ed dataframes (all the rows from the first, then all from the second, etc.).

I think the above is a decent TLDR on `merge` vs `concat` but see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) for a lengthy but much more comprehensive guide on using `merge`/`join`/`concat` with dataframes.